# jQuery Mobile fixed footer

Tags: jquery-mobile, footer, css-position

in a mobile website is my footer at fixed position,

but every time when I click in Iphone 4 on a form (input fields), my Iphone keyboard get opens and my footer is in this time not fixed.
when closing keyboard its all well.

only when my keyboard is open the footer is scrollable with the content,
I dont know why?

here is my css code

```
.bgfooter{
left: 0;
position: fixed!important;
right: 0;
top: 0!important;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1!important;
bottom: 0;

background:url('../images/background.png') no-repeat 0 0 !important;
```

}

my html code

```
...  
<div data-role="content">....</div>             
<div class="bgfooter" data-position="fixed"  data-role="footer" >.... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug open on this:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3072

I've recoded my app to avoid fixed footers in jQueryMobile. Things might change when 1.1 final is released.